my baked fire simulation is floating with a super small scale
I basically have a ecosphere emitting particles and I added a fluid simulation (fire + smoke, inflow) to that ecosphere with the flow source as a particle system so it could follow the particle system, I put the domain samples at 256, I checked the noise and adaptive domain, put the fire reactions speed at .4. bottom an top collisions are checked, i changed open vdb to uni cache, checked is resumable, switched from replay to modular. the initial velocity of the ecosphere is at 4, it has 7 sampling substeps, everything else is at default value. the fluid sim starts at 40 frames and ends at 150. I applied the scale too. im in cycles
but when I baked it, the fire is, one, outside the domain, two, way smaller, three not following the particle system, four,is floating, five, is ticking me off.
im using the M1 Mac Studio
here is a vid link:
https://streamable.com/kp7lhb
I was previously viewing it in replay, it looked kind of fine, but still is lacking.
does anyone know what is wrong? thanks
